# html, css: How to cause a div be presented on top of other divs

Tags: html, css

In facebook or likedin and many other sites there is search box in which you type in your search string and the results are presented right beneath it hiding everything else on this place as shown in the snapshot below taken from Likedin.

[image]

My question is how can this be done, how do I get this search `div` (or should it be something else than a `div`?) hide other parts of the page that appear to be at the same area on the page?

FWIW: some of my `div`s (that should be overridden) are defined as `position:fixed`.

Comment: you must use jquery widget calls : autocomplete

Comment: ALL the divs are position fixed?!

Comment: That "results" element is just placed there using CSS. Using z-index it's placed "on top of" other elements.

Comment: First and foremost, if all of your div's on your site are set to position: fixed, you are doing web wrong, and should start over.  As for this search box, speaking strictly to the styling.  It's just a box with position: absolute or fixed with a zindex and left/bottom parameters for positioning.

Comment: @Michael,@Mike, I edited the question. Not all the `div`s are positioned fixed but some of the `div` that should be overridden. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: This is typically called a modal or lightbox. Have a look at jQuery colorbox or fancybox.

Comment: @codehorse, z-index is wonderful. You can add it as an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use z-index , z-index with higher number appear on top of lower z-index

for example #div-1 would appear on top since div-2 has no z-index(which default is either 0 or the z-index of the div's parent), and div-3 has a smaller z-index value. But div-3 would appear on top of div-2.

```
#div-1 {
    z-index: 3523;
}

#div-2 {
}

#div-3 {
    z-index: 29;
}
```

Comment: Why have you used such big numbers? `1` did the trick for me :)